# Lost gimp 'recent document list' after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: gimp

On upgrading Ubuntu from 14.10 to 15.04 I had to reinstall some of my programs, one of which was the gimp. My system has the root directory in one partition and the home directory in a separate partition. When I do the Ubuntu upgrade I keep the original home partition intact. After installing the gimp I no longer have my recent file list from before the upgrade. It's going to be a pita to recreate this list so I'm wondering:

1. Where is the gimp recent file list kept?
2. Can I change the location of this list to somewhere in my home directory?

Thanks..

Comment: There is a temp file in `/home/<user-name>/.gimp-2.8/tmp/`, but I can't see anything in that folder..I guess your update must have cleared the 'dangling' entries (or have you moved those files?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one list of recently used files, which is used by Gimp and many other apps. It is `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`. If you open a file with Gimp (or any other app that supports the recently-used file), the file name will be added to `recently-used.xbel`. You may have a backup copy of that somewhere. Otherwise, you could recreate it by editing the current file `recently-used.xbel` and adding an entry for each Gimp file you want to have available. Such an entry would look like this:

```
  <bookmark href="file:///path/to/file" added="2015-09-05T10:28:53Z" modified="2015-09-05T10:36:40Z" visited="2015-09-05T10:28:54Z">
    <info>
      <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
        <mime:mime-type type="image/gif"/>
        <bookmark:groups>
          <bookmark:group>Graphics</bookmark:group>
        </bookmark:groups>
        <bookmark:applications>
          <bookmark:application name="GNU Image Manipulation Program" exec="&apos;gimp-2.8 %u&apos;" modified="2015-09-05T10:36:40Z" count="4"/>
        </bookmark:applications>
      </metadata>
    </info>
  </bookmark>
```

Comment: Thanks Jos, the backup copy is right there!  In addition to `recently-used.xbel` there are about a half dozen other files named `recently-used.xbel.76WFSX` etc. These are apparently archives created - I'm guessing - whenever the operating system is upgraded. Anyway the entries I need are in one of these files and I can copy them over to `recently-used.xbel`.

Comment: Good! If you are satisfied with my answer, please click the check mark next to the question, to mark the question as "answered".

Comment: One short followup on this. I tried copying a complete <bookmark> </bookmark> block from an archive file to the .xbel file and it didn't show up on the gimp recent files list. My guess is that the time stamps are out of order. However the archive does have the actual filenames so I just opened each one up in the gimp and the .xbel file was updated automatically. Thanks again